# Convert html file containing mathjax to pdf using reportlab django

Tags: django, pdf, pdf-generation, mathjax, reportlab

I would like to know how is it possible to convert an HTML file containing some Mathjax to pdf (in order to print it). I tried to make it work like this :

VIEWS.PY
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView

class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = "mytemplate.html"

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    
    context = super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(
            pagesize="A4",
            title="Hi Pierre!",
            **kwargs
        )
    context.update({'variable':12})
    return context
```

MYTEMPLATE.HTML

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}

{% block extra_style %}
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hi there!{{variable}}</h1>

        {% autoescape on %} 
            $$ \frac{a}{b} x=2 $$
        {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       ('^monpremierpdf.pdf$', HelloPDFView.as_view()),
                      )
```

But it doesn't give me the result I was expecting. And I still can see the "$$" in my pdf without any Latex inside.

If someone could explain me the easiest way to do this, it would be really helpful for the project I'm working on...

Thanks!

Comment: Last I checked, reportlab did not execute JavaScript, so MathJax will never run. You might be able to do something with mathjax-node if you can intercept the math fragments or the full html before it's passed to reportlabs.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution : use pdfcrowd

1°. Subscribe here : pdfcrowd.com
2°. they provide you a username and API key (first 100 tokens are free)
3°. run : pip install pdfcrowd
4°.

```
import pdfcrowd
def generate_pdf_view(request):
    path_to_html_file = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT,"templates/mytemplate.html")
    try:
        # create an API client instance
        client = pdfcrowd.Client("<username>", "<API_key>")

        # convert a web page and store the generated PDF to a variable
        pdf = client.convertFile(path_to_html_file)

         # set HTTP response headers
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
        response["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0"
        response["Accept-Ranges"] = "none"
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=myamazingPDF.pdf"

        # send the generated PDF
        response.write(pdf)
    except pdfcrowd.Error, why:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/plain")
        response.write(why)
    return response
```

And the result is exactly as I want...